# Cannot install devtools package in R on MacBook Air 2016

Tags: gcc, gfortran, devtools

I'm trying to install the CARD package in R from GitHub using devtools. I have when I run the following code:

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('YingMa0107/CARD', dependencies = TRUE)
```

I get this error:

```
─  installing *source* package ‘CARD’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   using C++ compiler: ‘Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)’
   using C++11
   using SDK: ‘’
   clang++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/opt/R/x86_64/include     -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c CARDfree.cpp -o CARDfree.o
   clang++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/opt/R/x86_64/include     -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c CARDref.cpp -o CARDref.o
   clang++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/opt/R/x86_64/include     -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -Wall -pedantic -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   clang++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/x86_64/lib -o CARD.so CARDfree.o CARDref.o RcppExports.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0 -L/opt/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0'
   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib'
   ld: library not found for -lgfortran
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   make: *** [CARD.so] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘CARD’
─  removing ‘/private/var/folders/wz/x1xnldhj4b3fsynpxk8g9sxm0000gn/T/Rtmp7Rik73/Rinsta6f047edd24e/CARD’
         -----------------------------------
   ERROR: package installation failed
Error: Failed to install 'CARD' from GitHub:
  ! System command 'R' failed
```

I have updated R (4.3.0) and RStudio (2023.03.0+386) and installed gcc on my terminal using homebrew but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks for your help!
Iwan

Comment: You need gfortran library installed according to your error. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS

Comment: Hi, I installed gfortran and this was the error that came up, sorry I didn't make that clear